# How can I accept a Teams call on a VM and direct the connection to my laptop?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, remote-desktop, teams

I work for Company A, which provides software engineering services to other companies. Company A has issued me a laptop; we have our own corporate Outlook and Teams services as well. Also, Company A has given me a phone number which will allow an outsider to "call" me on Teams and connect via voice.

My company has farmed me out to Company B as a contractor. Company B provided me with a corporate virtual machine, which I can reach using the laptop I was given by Company A (I run Remote Desktop Connection or `mstsc.exe`). Company B's VM is also set up with Company B's Outlook and Teams.

One thing I have noticed about using Teams on my VM is that the audio lag is unacceptable and even causes a feedback loop for some listeners. So **I can't have an effective audio Teams call on my VM**. However, I find that I can join Company B's Teams meetings from my laptop if I send myself an invite.

Here is my question. Sometimes I will *receive an inbound call* via Teams on Company B's VM. Because it is an incoming call and not a meeting, I can't directly forward it to my laptop. But I don't want to accept it on my VM. How can I handle this?

I am looking for

(a) A way to automatically forward all incoming Teams calls from the VM to the laptop, or

(b) An easy way to accept the call on the VM, invite myself to join from the laptop, and then disconnect from the call on the VM, so I can continue the voice call on the laptop. So far I have not found any way I can invite anyone outside Company B to its Teams calls, other than setting up an invite in Outlook and forwarding it (which takes too long).

Comment: What do either of the IT administrators have to say about your problem?  Any solution will require their help.  Have you asked them for assistance?

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your comment. What do you think I should ask the IT administrators to do?

Comment: Ask them the question you are asking us. One of them must have a solution, specifically, your actual primary employer since it’s their hardware. Seems the simplest solution is to have the second company contact you directly with your primary contact information or have your company provided another solution

Comment: You could call Teams on your phone from VM teams on laptop.  Disconnect laptop.  Take the call on phone or connect back to Teams on laptop.